# What happens when I don't satisfy trait bounds?

Tags: rust, traits

I have some code :

```rust
impl<K, V> Database<K, V>
where
    K: Eq + Hash,
    V: Clone,
```

Where I have `Database` defined like :

```rust
pub struct Database<K, V>
where
    K: Eq + Hash,
```

Note the absence of trait bounds on `V`. My question is what happens if I construct an instance of this object such that `V: !Clone`? Would my methods that depend on `V: Clone` simple panic? Or will the rust compiler catch it?

Comment: What happens if you try it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read this:

```
impl<K, V> Database<K, V>
where
    K: Eq + Hash,
    V: Clone,
{
    // methods
}
```

As:

> Implement these methods for `Database<K, V>` whenever `K` implements `Eq + Hash` and `V` implements `Clone`.

If those constraints are not met then those methods will not exist, and you'll see a compile error if you try to call them.

These constraints are different from the ones on the type itself. Those just affect if you can construct an instance of the type. It's actually quite common to omit all constraints on the type itself and only have them on the `impl` blocks.